# Запятая перед «да»

Tags: запятые

Ставится ли запятая перед «да» в нижеследующем предложении?

> По вечерам стабильно парюсь только я да и делаю это быстро.

Answer (score 2):

**ДА И** - союз, обозначающий неожиданный переход или завершение. Употребляется в разговорной речи.

В вашем случае, запятая нужна: `По вечерам стабильно парюсь только я, да и делаю это быстро`.